# Rails App - jQuery to display static text upon dynamic select

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a REQUEST form that has many CATEGORIES and CATEGORY has many PRODUCTS.  I have jQuery working to populate PRDOUCTS based on the CATEGORY selection:

requests.js.coffee:

```
jQuery ->
    $('#request_product_id').parent().hide()
    products = $('#request_product_id').html()
    console.log(products)
    $('#request_category_id').change ->
        category = $('#request_category_id :selected').text()
        options = $(products).filter("optgroup[label='#{category}']").html()
        console.log(options)
        if options
            $('#request_product_id').html(options)
            $('#request_product_id').parent().show()
        else
            $('#request_product_id').empty()
            $('#request_product_id').parent().hide()
```

Now I would like static text of product.description to display upon selecting the PRODUCT.

At the same time, I would like to display custom form partials to display depending on the selected PRODUCT.  For instance, if product.id = 1, render _product1.html.erb OR.... Just toggle DIVs based on product.id to show appropriate fields.

Here's my full _form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for(@request) do |f| %>
  <% if @request.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@request.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this request from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @request.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :category_id, "Select a Category:" %>
    <%= f.collection_select(:category_id, Category.sorted, :id, :name, :include_blank => true ) %>
  </div>

  <!--  BASED ON CATEGORY SELECTED ABOVE, LOAD CORRESPONDING PRODUCTS BELOW -->

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :product_id, "Select a Product/Service:" %>
    <%= f.grouped_collection_select :product_id, Category.sorted, :products, :name, :id, :name, include_blank: true %>
  </div>

  <!-- ALL OF THE ABOVE WORKS FINE... NOW....  -->
  <!--  BASED ON PRODUCT SELECTED ABOVE, LOAD CORRESPONDING PRODUCT DESCRIPTION AND CORRESPONDING FORM -->

  <div class="field">
    ::::  THIS WILL AUTO POPULATE WITH THE ABOVE-SELECTED PRODUCT.DESCRIPTION  ::::
  </div>

  <p></p>

  <div>
    <p>:::: BASED ON PRODUCT.ID, HIDE/SHOW SPECIFIC DIVS HERE. IF PRODUCT.ID IS NOT SPECIAL, DO NOT SHOW ANYTHING HERE</p>
  </div>

  <!--  THEN, NO MATTER WHAT THE PRODUCT.ID IS, THERE WILL BE A REQUESTOR_NOTE FOR FURTHER INFO -->

    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :requestor_note, "Please give full details below..." %>
    <%= f.text_area :requestor_note, :size => "50x6" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: How much dynamic content (products) do you have? Is it too much data to put all the products/descriptions/partials you'll need in the page? Or will you need AJAX?

Comment: For the descriptions, there are over 200 products, so I will need to pull dynamically.  For the custom form partial load, this will grow over time, but right now I have 200 generic products that don't need the custom form + 7 products that require special fields...

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add an ajax call to render your product form partial, something like the following should work (untested).  Please note that the names are made up.  With the following you don't have to have multiple `_product_form` partials which is better as you won't have to define new partials for every new product added to your system (don't know why you decided to go that route i.e. add a partial for every product).

```
$('#request_product_id').on('change', function(evt) {
  selected_product_id = $(this).val();
  $.ajax({
    url: 'my_controller/product_form',  //Note the my_controller and action here, i.e. change accordingly
    type: 'get', 
    data: { 'product_id=' + selected_product_id }
  });
});
```

**config/routes.rb**

```
get 'my_controller/product_form/:product_id', to: 'my_controller#product_form', constraints: { product_form: /\d+/ }
```

**my_controller.rb**

```
def product_form 
    @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])

    respond_to do |format|
        format.js
    end
end
```

**product_form.js.erb**

```
var target = $('#my_target_field'); // See notes below
target.html("<%= j render('_product_form') %>");
```

You need to add something that uniquely identifies the target `div` so that the jQuery selector can work easily.  You could add an `id` attribute e.g (in your _form.html.erb):

```
<div id="my_target_field" class="field">
  ::::  THIS WILL AUTO POPULATE WITH THE ABOVE-SELECTED PRODUCT DESCRIPTION  ::::
</div>
```

**_product_form.html.erb**

```
<div class="my_static_text_field"><%=@product.product_description %></div>
...
```

Comment: This is a two part question. All product.descriptions should display based on product selection. Only certain products will have custom partials.  For instance, Product=Move Employee, I need to capture a bunch of fields like from_facility, to_facility, from_room, to_room. Whereas, Product=New Employee, I need to capture name, title, supervisor, etc.  If there is a better way to display LOTS of fields that are only used when a certain product is selected, I'm all for it.

Comment: The other generic products will have no special partial, but just the category select, product select, static product.description load, followed by the further details text area.

Comment: If I build one _form.html.erb to hold all REQUEST fields, how would I toggle (hide/show) particular DIVs based on the product selected above it?  I will show the product.description for ALL PRODUCTS, then toggle certain DIVs below that to show relevant fields... is that a better approach?

Comment: @KatieM, You could add another `div` with the product id and use jQuery to show/hide using that product id selector.  Please post some code that you have and what you expect it to do, that way we can understand the problem better.

Comment: Ha - that's the problem, I don't have any code yet because I am new to jquery.  I posted my full form with DIVs indicating what I hope to achieve.  I will take another stab at this on my own and try to come back with something more concrete.  Thanks!